# how to get result based on 10 minutes interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find ten most search distinct destinations for 10 minutes interval?

```
    user_id             time        action  destination place
    2017032000000000097 00:00:00    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
    2017032000000000097 00:03:53    Click   Sant    Regina Elena 571
    2017032000000000097 00:01:16    Click   Regina  Regina Elena 572
    2017032000000000097 00:04:34    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
    2017032000000000129 00:07:32    Click   Berlin  MÃ¼ggelsee Berlin
    2017032000000000129 00:18:36    Click   GRC     SensCity Berlin Spandau
    2017032000000000129 00:16:12    Click   Berlin  Azimut Berlin City South
```

expected output/similar output

```
time            destination(top 10 during 10 minute interval) 
-------------   ---- 
00:00:00        NULL
00:10:00        Rimini,Sant,Regina
00:20:00        Berlin,Grc
00:30:00        NULL
```

i have tried below code,

```
select destination , count(user_id),time from click
where MINUTE(time)>= MINUTE(now())-10 and MINUTE(time)< minute(now()) and destination is not null
group by destination,MINUTE(time)>= MINUTE(now())-10 and MINUTE(time)< minute(now()) order by count(user_id) desc;
```

Comment: what is yout question exactly?

Comment: @Jonathan edited my question.

Comment: What exactly is your time format, your output doesn't make much sense? Is it DD:HH:MM?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is HH:MM:SS, i have edited my output

Comment: Why are the last two Berlin destinations part of the first row and why is the Rimini destination part of every row?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson top 10 searched destination irrespective of user_ids.

Comment: There is no user_id, I'm referring to the time column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176173/discussion-between-working-hard-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: No, write a question that makes sense instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have edited my input data and expected output, i want top 10 destinations for 10 minutes interval,by interval i am referring time column.

Comment: Why does `00:00:00` have all the distinct destination place??

Comment: @RaymondNijland edited my expected output.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @RaymondNijland

Comment: You probably need GROUP_CONCAT to get the concatenated column values shown in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution by below query.

```
select a.time_column,group_concat(a.destination order by ct desc) from  (select case 
            when time between '00:00:00' and '00:10:00' then '00:10:00'
            when time between '00:10:01' and '00:20:00' then '00:20:00'
            when time between '00:20:01' and '00:30:00' then '00:30:00'
        else '00:00:00' end as time_column 
        , destination
        , count(destination) ct
from click
group by time_column,destination
order by time_column,count(destination) desc limit 10)a
group by a.time_column;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the first three characters of each time, and aggregate over that substring.

So the first five times become `00:0` and the next three become `00:1`

This way, any times within a ten min interval get truncated to the same thing.

```
select substring(time,0,4) as truncTime, destination, count(*)
from table
group by truncTime
```

Gives you

```
truncTime  destination  count
00:0       Rimini       4
00:0       Berlin       1
00:1       Berlin       2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select destination , count(id) from your_table
where MINUTE(time)>= MINUTE(now())-10 and MINUTE(time)< minute(now()) 
group by destination 
LIMIT 10
```