# how to find second distinct hotel clicked by user

Tags: mysql, sql

```
userid  time        action  destination hotel
    97  00:00:00    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
    97  00:03:53    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
    97  00:01:16    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
    97  00:04:34    Click   Rimini  Regina Elena 57
   129  00:07:32    Click   Berlin  MÃ¼ggelsee Berlin
   129  00:18:36    Click   Berlin  SensCity Berlin Spandau
   129  00:16:12    Click   Berlin  Azimut Berlin City South
```

how to find second distinct hotel clicked by user,display null if user did not clicked on two distinct hotel.

expected output

```
userid    hotel(2nd distinct hotel clicked by user,null if not found)
97        NULL
129       Berlin    SensCity Berlin Spandau
```

Comment: `select distinct hotel order by time limit 1,1` ? something like that ?

Comment: @apokryfos i want for all the users.

Comment: Then add expected output at least since I assume you haven't any code to show us or?

Comment: expected output should **MATCH** the example data..

Comment: @RaymondNijland edited the expected output.

Comment: What MySQL version? use `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland 8.0.11

Comment: Posted a answer which works on older MySQL versions to.. @WorkingHard.. iam looking into a MySQL 8.0 only query also.

Comment: @RaymondNijland can you also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385586/how-to-find-top-10-items-based-on-10-minutes-interval question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question involves ranking..

There are multiple methods one method is use nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions to split out a `GROUP_CONCAT` string with a `ORDER BY` option function.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT   
   Table1.userId
 , (
     CASE
      WHEN
        COUNT(DISTINCT Table1.hotel) >= 2
      THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.destination ORDER BY Table1.time ASC)
            , ','
            , -1
          )
          , ','
          , 1
        )
      ELSE NULL
     END
    ) AS destination   
 , (
     CASE
      WHEN
        COUNT(DISTINCT Table1.hotel) >= 2
      THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              GROUP_CONCAT(Table1.hotel ORDER BY Table1.time ASC)
            , ','
            , -1
          )
          , ','
          , 1
        )
      ELSE NULL
     END
    ) AS hotel
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY 
 Table1.userId
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3x1QkG3AhmZ2dHAswSm1AY/3